# what is the difference between 802.1p and 802.1q

Tags: wireless-networking, vlan

I'm newbie in vlan networking with little knowledge and I'm quite confusing in both 802.1p and 802.1q. 
If one device is only 802.1p compatible, can this device work in vlan tag transferring?

The problem I'm facing is as in below:

I have two devices, AP WDS and Station WDS mode connecting via wireless, vlan tag100 switchA (AP end) and vlan tag100 switchB (Sta end) cannot ping to each other.
I can only ping from switch A to switch B via ethernet.

I suspected one of the devices are only 802.1p compatible. 
Appreciate if anyone can give me some hints in this case.

Comment: 802.1p is a quality of service protocol, not a VLAN tagging protocol.  You'd need .1q on both ends

Comment: I left this comment because it seemed like the 802.1p thing was confusing the problem.  If you are still stuck, you can [edit] your question, add some detail, and we might still be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

.1p is used in the Cisco world i.e. on the switches with the configuration commands of 'switchport voice vlan dot1p'.

.1Q refers to the IEEE L2 Frame tagging protocol.

The difference is that with respect to Voice traffic .1p is used by Cisco to inform the IP Phone to use the .1Q tag framing protocol between itself and the switch but use the ID value of 0.  The allowed values are 1-4094 so 0 seems odd but means that the switch tags all voice and data frames (with ID = 0) and marks the voice as CoS 5 (leaving the data as-is).

The switchport appears as an access port but receives frames that appear as trunked i.e. with the .1Q tag.

Comment: Could you add some reference to this answer supporting what you state?